# How to pass user credentials to web service?

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services

I am consuming a webservice using WSDL in windows application. When I try to use method, i get the following error:-

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was '"
>
> {"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}

I have user credentials but don't know how to pass it using c# code in windows application.

Comment: How are you consuming your web service? WCF?

Comment: wsdlsoap binding... i guess. I am reading it from wsdl.xml file. Or you mean what type of application i am using to consume web service then its Windows Application.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the how it is working for me:-

Config file setting looks like this:-

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="bindingName"  >
              <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
              </security>
            </binding>

          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://10.10.10.10:1880/testpad/services/Testwebservice"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="bindingName"
                contract=testService.GetData" name="test_Port1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

and here i am passing user credentials:-

```
 var ser = new GetDataClient();
 ser.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "userid";
 ser.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Pa$$word1";
```

Comment: What worked for me is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39357477/1025320)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to genereate your service client proxy using the method mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751905.aspx). Once you have an instance of your WCF client proxy, it will have a property `ClientCreditials` which you can populate as needed. 
Hope this helps.