# Consuming web service with c# and basic authentication

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, basic-authentication

I want to consume a web service with this code:

```
WebService.GenRelClient client = new WebService.GenRelClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = @"UserName";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = @"Password";
var response = client.returnString("test");
```

And my config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="GenRelClientPortBinding">
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
        </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint
          address="http://ws.domain.com/GenRel/GenRel"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="GenRelClientPortBinding"
          contract="WebService.GenRelClientPort"
          name="GenRelClientPort" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The request is sent to the web service and the response is sent back with incorrect message about that it need **Basic Authentication** because the request was sent probably without credentials, so I don't know where is the mistake.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I disagree that this question is a duplicate of the question with the title "How to pass user credentials to web service". The problem Bushwacka is faced with is that the server is configured to use Preemptive authentication. A very particular case that requires the client to send authentication information in the SOAP header. None of this is addressed in the question mentioned before.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For you to be able to call the web-service you will need to add security information to the SOAP header.

Click [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/drnick/2008/07/08/adding-headers-to-a-call-http-version/) to read an MSDN article that explains the basic principle.

Take a look at the code sample below and see if it solves your problem:

```
 var client = new WCClient();  
 using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
 {
     var httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
     httpRequestProperty.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " +
                  Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" +
                  client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password));
     OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;

     client.DoSomething();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I don't have access to the host, I can only consume the service. I tested sending of request over SoapUI tool and it works correctly, there I sent the request with UserName and Password with Pre-emptive authentication, so I would need to do in it in C#

Comment: Perfect now it is work well!

Comment: God bless you !

Comment: God bless you again!

Comment: God bless you too!

Comment: God bless you, your family and all your future descendants!

Comment: Three weeks I spent mucking around on this problem....  You fixed it! Thank you so much!!!