# Use wsdl with basic authentication .Net

Tags: c#, .net, wsdl, basic-authentication

I have a wsdl with basic auth protected, when i tried with postman or through browser its working..

to use it in my code, i have connected the service through visual code 2022 and proxy class has been created..

then i used following code to use its methods

```
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding
        {
            SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(500),
            MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
            AllowCookies = true,
            ReaderQuotas = XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max
        };

        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("https://test/test/.wsdl");
        ChannelFactory<TEST_Channel> factory = new ChannelFactory<TEST_Channel>(binding, address);

        factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "abcd";
        factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "1234";

        var f = factory.CreateChannel();
        f.someMethod(param);
```

But getting following error on calling the someMethod()

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException : The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Digest realm="SOAP-Server", nonce="aasdasdasd1231313", algorithm="MD5", qop="auth"'.
```

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Following is the solution worked for me from this [link][1]

```
        var client = new TEST_ChannelClient();
        using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
        {
            var httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            httpRequestProperty.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " +
                         Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<userName>" + ":" +
                         "Password"));
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;

            var b = await client.someMethod();
        }


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39354562/consuming-web-service-with-c-sharp-and-basic-authentication/39357477#39357477
```